# How to strip sensitive information from exception message in c#

Tags: c#, jwt

Currently in our logging we log the exception message like this :

```
string.Format(
    "caught exception while validating token, error detail:{0}", this.exception.ToString())
```

There is some sensitive information(jwt) in the exception message:

> System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenValidationException:
>   Jwt10315: Signature validation failed. Keys tried:
>   'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey
>   System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey'

I was thinking of parsing the exception message string, removing sensitive information and then logging it. Create a new exception object with this stripped data and then pass it to other API's

Is there any other way that i can do it?

Comment: Create your own exception ?

Comment: Why not return a generic "An error occurred" message? Or generic messages based on the exception type?

Comment: @Thomas : By creating my own exception i mean't the way Yuval has answered my question below logger.Log(e);
throw new MyExceptionMessage("We screwed up!");

Comment: this was an (hidden) suggestion ;)

Comment: Don't count on removing.  You will not know every format and the format may change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was thinking of parsing the exception message string, removing
>   sensitive information and then logging it.

Parsing out exception messages would probably be none trivial to get right, as you will have to deal with different information and message types. Instead, I would simply log the original exception message and throw a customized exception which roughly describes what happened:

```
try
{
    RunSensitiveMethod();
}
catch (SecurityTokenValidationException e)
{
    // Perhaps something fancier if needed.
    logger.Log(e);
    throw new MyCustomException("We screwed up!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Catch the exception on SecurityTokenValidationException and then throw a new custom exception of your own type that contains only the information that you want.  You will still be able to log it and you will know exactly what it means.